# В чем проблема медленной загрузки страницы?

Tags: sql, база-данных, wordpress, woocommerce, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть интернет-магазин на wordpress+woocommerce. Есть проблема, страница грузится до 12с, на сколько я понял причина в большом количестве запросов к базе данных (900 запросов). Установил плагин Query monitor. Вот что он показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что в первую очередь нужно править? Я так понимаю что проблема в том что происходят повторные запросы к базе данных?

Comment: Предлогаю проверить сайт на [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) или [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/), там вы сможете увидеть что замедляет загрузку, какое время обращения к серверу и т.д.

Comment: Уже все что можно там оптимизировал. Проблема именно в запросах. 900 запросов это слишком много я так понимаю

Comment: Можете сделать кэширование ваших запросов

Comment: Если все остальное оптимизировано, то страница с 900 запросами будет грузиться 1-2 секунды, есть опыт. Дело не в этом. А в чем - неизвестно. Ответить невозможно без анализа сайта и плагинов. И начинать надо, как правильно тут сказали, с pingdom waterfall.

Comment: @KAGGDesign 900 запросов в база на одну загрузку - это дикий ужас.

Comment: Встречались у клиентов и такие страницы. Тем не менее они не грузились по 12 сек.

Comment: @KAGGDesign 100 посетителей в минуту - это уже 90 000 запросов. И это весьма скромный трафик. Что делать, когда он увеличивается в 5-10 раз?

Comment: Вы какую тему здесь обсуждаете и за что ратуете?